# Using a PHP Function to Display an Image With Absolute Positioning?

Tags: php, image, function, css-position

One thing I have never used PHP for is on-demand image placement - but now that problem has come up for me...

I need a function which will, given some X and Y coordinates, place a .png, or .gif somewhere on screen, using some form of absolute positioning.

I'm afraid I have absolutely no idea where to start looking for such information. For me, PHP is about displaying data from databases. This is an utterly alien concept to me! :)

Comment: PHP can write HTML, so just write the HTML that you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this example helps you to get started.
I used HTML, CSS and PHP

```
<?php 
/*
 * here you can define your coordinates in pixel
 */
$myXCoordinate = '100px';
$myYCoordinate = '200px';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Your Page title</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .absolute-pos {
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;  /* here you could set a fixed pixel size, e.g. 200px */
    height: 160px; /* here you could set a fixed pixel size, e.g. 200px */
    left: <?php echo $myXCoordinate; ?>;
    top: <?php echo $myYCoordinate; ?>;
  }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <p>showing the logo of wikipedia [source: upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png]</p>
  <img class="absolute-pos" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png" alt="Some description." />
</body>
</html>
```

Copy this code and save it to a php-file, e.g. "index.php". Then change the values for $myXCoordinate and $myYCoordinate. This will change the absolute position of your image.